# How to controll selected option by state after api call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let say I have a useState to store a user object:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
   name: "",
   age: "",
   type: ""
})
```

and a select box to show the type

```
<select
   className="input"
   value={user.type}
   onChange={handleType}

>
   <option value='A'>A</option>
   <option value='B'>B</option>
</select>
```

I want to call a api to get the user data and the selected option will change to user.type

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://api.test.com/users/1", {})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setUser(res.data.user);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

However, the selected option does not change.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you have there. What exactly is the result of the API call?

Comment: @DBS the return is {name: "Peter",age: "11",type: "B"}. I got some input box to show name and age. It is working for the text input box to show the data return by api. However, it is not working in select box. It keeps showing the first option.

Comment: if the property `type` of `res.data.user` is neither "A" or "B" the select elemnt will keep showing the first option i.e "A"

Comment: @Kenzo please just try to replace `setUser(res.data.user)`  by `setUser({ name: "ahmed", age: "26", type: "B" });` and tell me is the select value still shows A

Answer (score 0):

You can spread the response like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://api.test.com/users/1", {})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setUser(prev => ({...prev, ...res.data.user}));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my example could help you. if you update data to the value of select, updated data is not included in the options list. the select value will not update.

- so, when you update the value of select, after the API call.
- update option-list either.

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-wu-hl6vw6?file=/src/App.js)